# I cannot run pyinstaller on my computer even though I have installed it

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, pyinstaller

This is the problem right here, do you have any advice for that?
[image]

installed pip and pyinstaller, but still got this error message when I tried to convert my project into an .exe.

Answer (score 1):

From [Pyinstaller installation guide](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/installation.html#verifying-the-installation):

> If you cannot use the `pyinstaller` command due to the scripts directory not being in `PATH`, you can instead invoke the `PyInstaller` module, by running `python -m PyInstaller` (pay attention to the module name, which is case sensitive). This form of invocation is also useful when you have PyInstaller installed in multiple python environments, and you cannot be sure from which installation the `pyinstaller` command will be ran.

So you may run it as e.g.:

```
python -m PyInstaller some_system.py
```

Or, as the issue seems that `PATH` Windows environment variable doesn't include Python's `Script` folder, it'd better to fix it. From the same guide:

> If the command is not found, make sure the execution path includes the proper directory:
>
> Windows: C:\PythonXY\Scripts where XY stands for the major and minor Python version number, for example C:\Python38\Scripts for Python 3.8)

To fix you may run `where python` to get exact location of Python on your machine (let's say it shows `C:\Python38\`). Then add to `PATH` env variable `Scripts` folder inside it (in this example it'd be `C:\Python38\Scripts\`)